# Are browsers supposed to redirect to the URL of a Flask POST request?

Tags: python, html, google-chrome, flask

The index page of my Flask app contains an HTML form (to receive user input), and this HTML form sends the user input to another endpoint (/output) via a POST request, where it's then processed and a simple output is returned. But curiously, when the output is returned, it's returned *at* the /output endpoint (url). But how do I make sense of this, given that navigating to a new URL represents a GET request? Shouldn't a POST request not change the URL in your browser at all? I also defined by /output endpoint to only accept POST requests, so I know there's no GET requests going on behind the scenes here. (For context, I'm running Google Chrome on Windows.)

Does Flask perhaps automatically return output *at* the endpoint specified, regardless of whether you made a POST or a GET request to that endpoint(url)? If that's the case, then not all URL changes in your browser's search bar represent GET requests, apparently. I'm just stumped on what to make of this since I never redirected or made a GET request to the /output url, and I'm brand new to webdev so would greatly appreciate any insight. Thanks so much!!

Here's an MRE:

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('form.html')

@app.route('/output', methods=['POST'])  # Only accepts POST requests
def output():
    return 'A POST request was made; input1 = ' + request.form.get('input1')
    # The browser navigates to /output when the above is returned...how?

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

form.html:

```
<form action="/output" method="post">
Input 1: <input type="string" name="input1">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "it's returned at the /output endpoint".  Clients make requests of endpoints.  Servers just return HTML.  There's nothing endpoint-ish in the server's return.  Based on the HTML, the browser is navigating to `/output`.  That's what your `<form>` asks it to do.  The server is just responding to that request.

Comment: To start, the browser navigates to "/", and your "/" handler returns an HTML form.  Upon a click, the browser navigates to "/output" supplying POST data.  The server responds to that "/output" request with more HTML (presumably).  A POST request absolutely does change the URL in the browser's header.  That's how HTTP works.

Comment: @TimRoberts - Interesting. So essentially when you POST something to a url, the browser inherently navigates to that url? My impression was that the “POSTing” happens in the backend, and anything you “see” (that is, any HTML you receive), is obtained via a GET request. But it seems POST requests retrieve data too? (Thanks again for your clear explanations!)

Comment: Right.  ALL HTTP requests are essentially identical in this regard -- even the obscure ones like PUT and DELETE.  The only difference is how the data gets sent: part of the URL, or a separate data section after the headers.

Comment: @TimRoberts - I see. This is great to know. Thanks so much for taking the time to read and answer my question, and for your contributions to the SO community more generally. Wishing you a bug-free future.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't a POST request not change the URL in your browser at all?

POST means *data* will not appear in bar (as part of URL), not that URL will not change *at all*.

Comment: I see - makes sense! So in line with Tim in his comment on my post above, essentially a POST request sometimes *retrieves* data too and that data is shown at the url specified in the POST request? My understanding was that POSTs don’t redirect at all, but it looks like  that’s false. Thanks for taking the time to respond to my question!